# [vscode extension API]: How to create communication channel between javascript included in `vscode.previewHtml` and outside thread?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The thing is, i am trying to create a tool with `vscode.previewHtml` command, I need some javascript in it listening on user's action, and send a signal to outside thread, so that i can do few high cost "native" job in background, and refresh the `previewHtml` with new content.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "outside thread" you actually mean the hosting environment (VS code). There is no direct way (e.g. a listener/callback/method) to communicate, but you can use `postMessage` like so:

```
/* This is in a .js file you include in previewHTML. */
function exportToSVG(type) {
    let html = document.querySelectorAll('html')[0];
    let svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg')[0];
    const args = { name: objectName, type: type, svg: svg.outerHTML, html: html.outerHTML };
    window.parent.postMessage({
        command: "did-click-link",
        data: `command:_antlr.saveSVG?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args))}`
    }, "file://");

}
```

In vscode only a few commands are handled. One is that `did-click-link` command. You then can register to that command in your extension and do the actual work:

```
// This is in your extension code (usually the activate() method).
context.subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('_antlr.saveSVG', (args: { name: string, type: string, svg: string, html: string }) => {
        window.showInputBox({
            value: workspace.getConfiguration("antlr4." + args.type)["saveDir"] + "/" + args.name + ".svg",
            placeHolder: "<Enter full file name here>",
            prompt: "Enter the name to an svg file."
        }).then((value: string) => {
...
```

You can use the same approach for the other direction. See for instance the markdown preview extension how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that's the best solution i found now